# why typescript throws Binding element 'target' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get the correct type for this function parameter

```js
  const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    setFormValues({
      ...formValues,
      [target.name]: target.value,
    });
  };
```

its throwing me an error that didn't crash the app but I know its not a good practice.

to give more context, all the fields that are changing are strings.

Comment: How does this function get used? I'm guessing something like `<input onChange={handleInputChange}>`?

Comment: Seems like TS can't infer the type from how `handleInputChange` is used. Without showing us how it's used we cannot really help you either.

Comment: If you are new, use `({ target }: any)` until you understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's telling you that because you haven't told it what the type of the parameter is.

You need to tell it what the type is. There are a couple of ways:

1. Type the constant you're assigning the function to; or
2. Directly type the parameter

#### Type the constant you're assigning the function to

You can do that with the `ChangeEventHandler` type, which is generic, taking the type of the element as a type argument:

```typescript
import { ChangeEventHandler } from "react";

// ...

const onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = ({currentTarget}) => {
// type −−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(`${currentTarget.name} => ${currentTarget.value}`);
};
```

#### Directly type the parameter

The parameter is an event object which has a `currentTarget` property, so if (for instance) this is being used on an `HTMLInputElement`, you can use the type `{ currentTarget: HTMLInputElement }`:

```typescript
const handleInputChange = ({ currentTarget }: { currentTarget: HTMLInputElement }) => {
// type −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
};
```

Or you can use `ChangeEvent<T>`:

```typescript
import { ChangeEvent } from "react";

// ...

const handleInputChange = ({ currentTarget }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
// type −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
};
```

---

Note I used `currentTarget` rather than `target`. It doesn't usually matter for `input` elements (`target` and `currentTarget` are always be the same if the handler is on the `input`, not its parent/ancestor), but it does for `button` elements and some others (since `target` might be a descendant element). And it matters if you're handling `change` on a parent/ancestor element instead of on the `input` directly.

Comment: thanks TJ for the explanation, was very helpful!

Comment: this works with svelte also when I try to use js sample on my ts code. thanks